# SP (Service Provider) Multidomain

Tags: apache, saml, adfs, shibboleth

I'm using 2 Apache and Shibboleth machines for the same web portal configured as SP (Service Provider).

One domain is "domain.com" and the other is "www.domain.com".

Do you know if it is possible to configure both services on 1 single machine?

Thank you!